# Problems working with arrays of user defined type

Tags: python, vba

Can someone please explain if arrays work differently in VBA. How is the data stored here. I am trying convert this into python

In below VBA code how is data stored in array here? If it was `fldinfo(i)="NEW_NAME"` then I could see data is being stored in that particular index position. But adding `Name` in `fldinfo(i).Name` is confusing me.

I am new to VBA FYI and trying to convert this into python

```
Type FIELDCB
    Name As Long       
    type As Integer
    length As Integer
    decimals As Integer
    nulls As Integer
End Type

Dim fldinfo() As FIELDCB

i = 1
While ....
  fldinfo(i).Name = "NEW_NAME"
```

Comment: You need to give your array a size before using it `Dim fldinfo() As FIELDCB` declares it as an array but it has no elements. Use something like `Dim fldinfo(4) As FIELDCB` and it will add elements with index `0` to `4`. • Actually your question is very unclear because you did not describe what your actual problem is.

Answer (score 1):

Define a class for `FieldCV`:

```
class FieldCV:    
    def __init__(self, Name, type, length, decimals, nulls):
        self.Name = Name
        self.type = type
        self.length = length
        self.decimals = decimals
        self.nulls = nulls
```

Define the array that you will use to store your objects:

```
 array_of_field_cv = []
```

Let's assume you want to add 5 objects to your array:

```
for i in range(0, 5):
    # instantiate a object of FieldCV type and initialize it according to your needs. I have done a very simple dummy initialization
    field_cv = FieldCV(Name="NewName", type=i, length=i, decimals=i, nulls=i)

    # Add the object to the array
    array_of_field_cv.append(field_cv)
```

If you want to visualize the objects in your array:

```
for field_cv in array_of_field_cv:
    print(field_cv.__dict__)
```

Comment: Thanks Tajinder for detailed explanation. I believe this is what i need.